# Nose test runner finding all tests except a tag

Tags: python, tags, nosetests

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to have the nose test runner run all tests except for those with a specific tag. Looks like this is possible with attributes but I don't see if there's a way to do it with tags, which are a subset of attributes.

Currently I use tags by calling

```
nosetests -a tags='tag'
```

my tagged tests look like:

```
@attr(tags=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
    def test_some_stuff(self):
```

But if I want to run all test except 'baz' tagged, how would I do that?

I've tried expressions like

```
nosetests -A 'not baz'
nosetests -a '!baz'
nosetests tags='!baz'
```

But those don't seem to have any effect on anything but attributes. And I don't see an example of excluding tags in the docs: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html

I'd rather not have to add a new tag just for exclusion to this large test suite I'm working with and have to remember to always add a fake 'exclusion tag'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to flatten your tags. The way you specify it means you have *one* attribute, with a complex value of list.

Instead, specify the whole range of tags as immediate attributes.

```
 # coding: utf-8
 from nose.plugins.attrib import attr


 @attr("foo", "bar", "baz")
 def test1():
     print "I'm test1"


 @attr("foo")
 def test_2():
     print "I'm test2"
```

Then `nosetests -a '!bar' /tmp/test.py` works as desired.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Was just attempting that idea, appreciate the help!